# What is the website that returns expression and approximation when we enter a number?

Tags: soft-question

I remember a **website** where I **entered** like 0.2954 and it **returned**  "It's maybe $sin(0.3)$ ad $\varepsilon=0.001$
any help ?

Comment: probably you mean Wolfram Alpha?

Comment: No no that's a blue website that was returning every close function given a number, can wolframe do that ?

Comment: For possible closed formulas for a number, Wolfram Alpha is in fact very useful and powerful. I remember the inverse symbolic calculator. Do you mean that ?

Comment: May be the Inverse Symbolic Calculator: https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au

Comment: Thanks (it gave me error) but the good one is : https://isc.carma.newcastle.edu.au/advanced

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're asking about [RIES - Find Algebraic Equations, Given Their Solution](http://mrob.com/pub/ries/) (by the famous Robert Munafo).